# How to insert created_date in PostgreSQL using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table called `users` in a PostgreSQL database. It has `name`, `country` and `created_date` columns. If I insert a new user record with `name` and `country` values, `created_date` got inserted automatically. When I tried to do the same using Ruby code, `created_date` field is null.  My definition for create is given below. How can I insert `created_date` automatically.

```
def create
    @new_user = User.new(params[:user])
    @new_user.save
end
```

Note: `params[:user]` contains `name` and `country` values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails will automatically manage only created_on and created_at columns as you can see from [ActiveRecord::Timestamp](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb) source. Difference between **_at** and **_on** is that **_at** contains full datetime, while **_on** contains only date. If you use migrations you can create 'created_at' and 'updated_at' with t.timestamps.